# does IBM Watson IOT platform accepts text/string value?

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, esp32

I've successfully sent value of float number=5 from my esp32 to IBM Watson IoT platform and it got captured or received in the board which I created by selecting number in the board but when I'm sending a string or text value instead of number then it was not able to capture so now im confused because while creating the board I've set to text value for capturing or receiving string/text.
Here is the code snippet that I used to send my number value but when I change to string value it does not work so any suggestion:

float number=5;
String text="hello";

```
    String payload = "{\"d\":{\"Name\":\"" DEVICE_ID "\"";
          payload += ",\"text\":";
          payload += text;
          payload += "}}";
```

Comment: I'd suggest you share the code that *doesn't* work and some explanation for why you think it doesn't work - do you get an error compiling it? If so, what's the error? Does Watson indicate an error to you? Does it just not show up?

Comment: there was no error the only thing is that it is not able to capture the string/text value in the board in IBM Watson  yeah so you can say it does not show up...

Comment: Here is the code: String text="hello";

    String payload = "{\"d\":{\"Name\":\"" DEVICE_ID "\"";
          payload += ",\"text\":";
          payload += text;
          payload += "}}";

Comment: Please edit your question and include it there, not in the comments,

Answer (score 0):

I'd think you should enclose your string literal in double-quotes too, here the JSON will be malformed as it will end up as:
`{"d":{"Name":"DEVICE_ID","text":hello}}`
So the `hello` text is an invalid JSON token. Should be written as:

```
String payload = "{\"d\":{\"Name\":\"" DEVICE_ID "\"";
          payload += ",\"text\":\"";
          payload += text;
          payload += "\"}}";
```